# Getting issue file_put_contents(C:\xampp\htdocs\NityamProject\storage\framework\views/32e449593cd5fd22dd806fdf6e7d0f93eb700245.php)

Tags: laravel

I was deploy laravel7 folder from localhost to Server. All file successfully Deploy but I am getting below error.

```
file_put_contents(C:\xampp\htdocs\NityamProject\storage\framework\views/32e449593cd5fd22dd806fdf6e7d0f93eb700245.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Anyone have idea how to solve this. I have access only FTP filezila. Dont have any access command prompt nd all.
Help me in this

Comment: clear your view cache by `php artisan view:clear`  before uploading.

Comment: @zahid hasan emon, I have only ftp access. Cant run any command.

Comment: do it locally. and then upload.

Comment: @zahid i need to upload whole folder ?

Comment: you can upload the whole project or just the respective storage folder.

Comment: Ok sure i will do that.

Comment: @zahid error comes after upload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete **config.php** file inside `bootstrap >> cache >> config.php`

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan view:clear
php artisan route:clear
```

If you do not have access then you can call this command by using `web.php` file too

```
Route::get('clear_cache', function () {
    \Artisan::call('config:cache');
    \Artisan::call('view:clear');
    \Artisan::call('route:clear');
    dd("Cache is cleared");
});
```

Comment: Can i do this on local commamnd promt and upload again?  Before i was delete ( config.php file inside bootstrap >> cache >> config.php) this file . But geeting error "file not found"

Comment: Try to clear the caches first, but using artisan call, If this won't work then only delete that file, You won't get the error if you delete the file, that is the cache file

Comment: First need to do delete config.php and after that need to do php artsan command, right?

Comment: Both all clear the caches, you can go with first delete file, m then clear the caches

Comment: Means first delete that config.php file then do 3 php artisan command right?

Comment: Yes, do it, and for next time if you want to clear the cache then run url

Comment: I was delete this file from direct server , I am getting error "404 Not Found"

Answer (score 0):

Delete all the files in `storage\framework\views` and start fresh, they are cached view files.

This normally can be done by doing `php artisan view:clear`

Comment: @babalubs ,Dont have any file inside storage \framework\views for delete